# BL manga about a boy exiled from his family, who goes to school in the hopes of getting back in

Tags: identification-request, manga

I was trying to find a yaoi manga that I know is on mangago but I didn't save the name. All I remember is that it had less than 10 chapters. Summary is that a boy got exiled from his family by his grandfather after being framed having sexual relations with men. Next, he has to go to school to have any hope of getting back in. (There is also a leaf confession for some reason.) His ex finds out he was framed and his grandfather apologized and lets him back in the family. It's definitely Japanese.

Comment: Hello and welcome to LitSE. Please [edit your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/25533/edit) to include additional details, such as when and where you read the book, roughly when it was published, what it looked like, etc. Read the [tag info wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for suggestions about what kinds of details will help others identify the book for you. Thanks!